# How to duplicate keybinding in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want the control-L key combination to move the cursor right in addition to the arrow key, but assigning that key combination to cursorRight removes the right arrow association.  How can I add an additional key assignment without overwriting the current one?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.  after assigning the cursor movement to a control key combo, I clicked the icon tooltipped as "open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)" at the top right, which put me in the editor for keybindings.json, then I was able to find the original entry which had a minus sign in front ("-cursorRight") then I took out the minus sign, saved it, and it works. I think I could have just copied any entry as well